# Kubernetes Snapshots

Tags: kubernetes

I have an on-premise rancher server and there are two clusters in it. Let's get them cluster A and cluster B. In cluster A, I am creating a db snapshot and I need to copy that snapshot into cluster B. I am not a kubernetes expert therefore can someone help me with good ideas to achieve this or some reference materials that I could further refer to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to synchronize data between clusters. First off, see if your hypervisor supports [volume](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/replication.html) [replication](https://www.nutanix.com/blog/nutanix-dr-multi-site-recovery). That way, you can copy data across to another volume and mount that volume into the applications in the secondary cluster.

Another approach would be to use Velero with Restic to backup the volumes to an object store (min-io/s3) and then restore those in the second cluster as shown in [this example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-digitalocean-using-velero).

OpenEBS sounds like another viable option but I haven't had a chance to work with it yet. Linstor is another solution I have heard of.

Comment: Thanks brother. I'll try to figure out one of your idea